# Efficient way of handling multiple sorting and filtering using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jsf-2

I'm using JPA 2.0, Mojarra 2.1.9 and its component library Primefaces 3.5. I have a table in MySQL database named `state_table` with three columns.

- state_id (BigInt)
- state_name (Varchar)
- country_id (BigInt)

`state_id` is a auto-generated primary key and `country_id` is a foreign key that references a primary key of the `country` table.

---

This table is mapped by its corresponding entity class named `StateTable` and the data held by this table are displayed in a Primefaces `DataTable`, `<p:dataTable>...</p:dataTable>`.

The `DataTable` column header contains a clickable sort area, `<div>` for each column with a sort direction for sorting, when this area is clicked, a String, either `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING` representing the sort order is rendered and a text box for filtering (searching) in which a user enters a search item for each column.

---

So ultimately, what I get in JSF managed bean is a List of type `java.util.List<org.primefaces.model.SortMeta>` representing sort orders of the columns of the `DataTable` that a user wishes.

And a Map of type `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>` representing the search column names as keys and search items of the corresponding columns as values (a search item is entered by a user in a text box on the column header of each column of `DataTable`).

---

In short, I use `List<SortMeta>` for sorting and `Map<String, String>` for filtering/searching.

My code in one of the DAOs to get a list of rows after sorting and filtering is as follows.

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<StateTable> getList(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, String>filters)
{
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<StateTable> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(StateTable.class);
    Metamodel metamodel=entityManager.getMetamodel();
    EntityType<StateTable> entityType = metamodel.entity(StateTable.class);
    Root<StateTable>root=criteriaQuery.from(entityType);
    Join<StateTable, Country> join = null;

    //Sorting

    List<Order> orders=new ArrayList<Order>();

    if(multiSortMeta!=null&&!multiSortMeta.isEmpty())
    {
        for(SortMeta sortMeta:multiSortMeta)
        {
            if(sortMeta.getSortField().equalsIgnoreCase("stateId"))
            {
                orders.add(sortMeta.getSortOrder().equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)?criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(StateTable_.stateId)):criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(StateTable_.stateId)));
            }
            else if(sortMeta.getSortField().equalsIgnoreCase("stateName"))
            {
                orders.add(sortMeta.getSortOrder().equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)?criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(StateTable_.stateName)):criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(StateTable_.stateName)));
            }
            else if(sortMeta.getSortField().equalsIgnoreCase("country.countryName")) // Yes, Primefaces DataTable renders this ugly name in case of a nested property representing a foreign key relationship.
            {
                join = root.join(StateTable_.countryId, JoinType.INNER);
                orders.add(sortMeta.getSortOrder().equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)?criteriaBuilder.asc(join.get(Country_.countryName)):criteriaBuilder.desc(join.get(Country_.countryName)));
            }
        }
    }

    //Filtering/searching

    List<Predicate>predicates=new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    if(filters!=null&&!filters.isEmpty())
    {
        for(Entry<String, String>entry:filters.entrySet())
        {
            if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("stateId"))
            {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(StateTable_.stateId), Long.parseLong(entry.getValue())));
            }
            else if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("stateName"))
            {
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(StateTable_.stateName), "%"+entry.getValue()+"%"));
            }
            else if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("country.countryName"))// Yes, Primefaces DataTable renders this ugly name in case of a nested property representing a foreign key relationship.
            {
                if(join==null)
                {
                    join = root.join(StateTable_.countryId, JoinType.INNER);
                }
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(join.get(Country_.countryName), "%"+entry.getValue()+"%"));
            }
        }
    }

    if(predicates!=null&&!predicates.isEmpty())
    {
        criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }

    if(orders!=null&&!orders.isEmpty())
    {
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(orders);
    }
    else
    {
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(StateTable_.stateId)));
    }
    TypedQuery<StateTable> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setFirstResult(first).setMaxResults(pageSize);
    return typedQuery.getResultList();        
}
```

This works as expected but as it can be noticed, the `if-else if` ladder inside the `foreach` loop can contain many conditional checks as the number of columns in a database table are increased.

Each column requires a conditional check for both sorting and searching. Is there an efficient way to get rid of these conditional checks that can ultimately remove or at least minimize this `if-else if` ladder?

P.S. In case of country, I'm doing sorting and searching on `countryName` (which is available in the parent table `country`) rather than `countryId`. Hence, I'm using `Join`, in this case.

Comment: You probably have to use introspection (or Commons BeanUtils), to get rid of the if-else-if's. Something like: "if the key does not contain a dot, get the property with this name from the main table; if it contains a dot, get the property from the joined table". This will create a constant-size algorithm for any number of properties.

Answer (score 3):

I believe, you should not mix your architecture layers. 
`SortMeta` is a GUI class. If you want to change your GUI-Framework, or use another one, you have to refactor your Finder. Therefore you should not use `SortMeta` (GUI-Class) in your business layer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to wrap parameters

```
int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, String>filters
```

And don't mix classes from primefeaces and dao as suggested in axels comment.
When creating this wrapper convert this view classes to some custom backend classes.

in some object. I have `DataTableProperites` class. It is much readible and convenient to use.
Instead of `multiSortMeta!=null&&!multiSortMeta.isEmpty()` use [CollectionUtils.isEmpty](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.util.Collection%29)

I recommend you to extract nested ifs and loops to methods. Maybe when you extract them you will find some place where you can remove duplication.

Comment: Regarding CollectionUtils.isEmpty: or you can just leave your null check as is and remove !multiSortMeta.isEmpty() that doesn't do anything anyway... And leave the "commons" dependency for what it is (something not *that* common).

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code is not very readable:

```
if(sortMeta.getSortField().equalsIgnoreCase("stateId"))
{
    orders.add(sortMeta.getSortOrder().equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)?criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(StateTable_.stateId)):criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(StateTable_.stateId)));
}
else if(sortMeta.getSortField().equalsIgnoreCase("stateName"))
{
    orders.add(sortMeta.getSortOrder().equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)?criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(StateTable_.stateName)):criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(StateTable_.stateName)));
}
else if(sortMeta.getSortField().equalsIgnoreCase("country.countryName")) // Yes, Primefaces DataTable renders this ugly name in case of a nested property representing a foreign key relationship.
{
    join = root.join(StateTable_.countryId, JoinType.INNER);
    orders.add(sortMeta.getSortOrder().equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)?criteriaBuilder.asc(join.get(Country_.countryName)):criteriaBuilder.desc(join.get(Country_.countryName)));
}
```

What I would do is to store several things in local variables, so you don't have to repeat calls to getters over and over again. Since your call to `orders.add` is performed in all if-statements, it can be placed after the ifs to reduce code duplication.

```
String sortField = sortMeta.getSortField();
YourType sortOrder = sortMeta.getSortOrder();
YourType id = null;
if(sortField.equalsIgnoreCase("stateId") || )
{
    id = root.get(StateTable_.stateId);
}
else if(sortField.equalsIgnoreCase("stateName"))
{
    id = root.get(StateTable_.stateName);
}
else if(sortField.equalsIgnoreCase("country.countryName")) 
{
    // Yes, Primefaces DataTable renders this ugly name in case of a nested property representing a foreign key relationship.
    join = root.join(StateTable_.countryId, JoinType.INNER);
    id = join.get(Country_.countryName);
}

if (id != null)
    orders.add(sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING) ? criteriaBuilder.asc(id) : criteriaBuilder.desc(id));
```